# Overful hbox (How to make the sentence in a table into 2 line?)

Tags: tables, boxes

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|c |c |c |c |c |c}
         1 & 2 & 3 & 4jkjhkjkhjhkjkjkjl & 5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa & 6dasdsadasdasdasdasdsadasdsa \\
         \hline
         1 & 2 & 3 \\
         1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{tes}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Output:

[image]

How to make it "5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa" into 2 line?
For example:

```
5fsdsadsadasd
sadsadasdsadsa
```

Comment: You can use `p{<width>}` column type for last three columns. It will works fine with natural words (which eventually can be hyphenated).

Comment: you should supply a proper test file, you have given no indication of the required page width, also `5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa` not being a real word, which means that it will not hyphenate and so automatic line breaking is harder, is your real text natural language text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I am not sure how to check my page width. I used a template for it. And yes, {5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa} can be a real word, just an example

Comment: @user193541 then it is a bad example as breaking `5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa` automatically is far harder than breaking natural language text, so both examples that have have are probably not suitable for natural language. You could have posted a complete document just useing `article` as both answers have done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't indicated *how wide* columns 4, 5, and 6 are supposed to be. Hence, I'll assume they're supposed to be *equally wide*. I will further assume that the overall width of the tabular material should be `\textwidth`, i.e., as wide as the text block. The code below employs a `tabularx` environment and three columns of type `X`.

Since there is no obvious way -- to me at least... -- to decide where the strings "5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa" and "6dasdsadasdasdasdasdsadasdsa" should be split, I'll use the `\seqsplit` macro to force line breaks to occur whenever the strings reach the widths of the respective cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,seqsplit}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a ever so slightly more open "look"
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c |c |c |X |X |X |}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 
         \seqsplit{4jkjhkjkhjhkjkjkjl} & 
         \seqsplit{5fsdsadsadasdsadsadasdsadsa} & 
         \seqsplit{6dasdsadasdasdasdasdsadasdsa} \\
         \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{tes}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, work very well.

Comment: Can you explain what "\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} " means? Is this mean 2 line?

Comment: @user193541 - `\extrarowheight` is a length parameter that governs much extra vertical whitespace is inserted at the top of each row; its default value is `0pt`. Try is out an a `tabular` environment -- first with the value set at its default, then with a value of `2pt`. I think you'll notice the difference right away.

Comment: Thanks. However, the words is combine without a spacing in the orginal words. Meaning let say '\seqsplit{Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3l}'. It will become 'Testing1testing2Testing3' and not 'Testing 1 testing 2 Testing 3'

Comment: @user193541 - Don’t use `\seqsplit` if there’s no need for it.

Comment: thanks. Does it works with `\usepackage{multirow}`.

Comment: @user193541 - Post new queries to ask substantially new questions.

Comment: thanks. I think what you mean is post a new question which I had posted with a new topic

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]% h on its own is asking for trouble
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|c |c |c |c |c |c}
         1 & 2 & 3 & 4jkjhkjkhjhkjkjkjl & 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}5fsdsadsadasd\\sadsadasdsadsa\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}6dasdsadasdasd\\asdasdsadasdsa\end{tabular} \\
         \hline
         1 & 2 & 3 \\
         1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{tes}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```